# Is "got held up" a phrasal verb?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

> "I'm sorry, I got held up."

Is "got held up" a phrasal verb, or "got" is a normal verb and only the "held up" part is the phrasal one?

Comment: It's a _get_-passive clause. "Held up" is the verbal idiom comprising verb+preposition. You can tell that "get" is not part of the idiom because it can be replaced by "be" in the _be_-passive equivalent "I was held up".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what the other two answers are trying to say is that *hold up* is a phrasal verb, but not *get held up*.

*Get* + *{past participle form of verb, phrasal or not}* + *X* can mean

- became X (e.g. "I got massaged at the massage parlor") - this definitely has an informal flavor to it.
- entered a situation where he/she/it became X, typically unwanted or unexpected (e.g. "I got lost after I turned on 3rd street")
- received the consequence of an action which made him/her/it become X, typically unwanted (e.g. "I got screwed over really good by my boss's lawyer")

Answer (score 0):

The verb in this sentence is "Got" which is the past form of the verb "to get". Being held up in this sentence example is the object.

To get + Place Expression is the form that was being used.

Comment: It's a _get_-passive clause. "Held up" is verbal idiom comprising verb+preposition, but it's not the object of "get", rather a catenative complement of "get".